# SQL Columns the same value

Tags: sql

I am no programmer but dabble enough to get in trouble. What I am looking to do is I have two columns one is named Email and the other is alert_email. I need the Email value to propagate to the alert_email for each user account. I need this for maintenance and the best way I have found to do this is run via sql commands. Here are some of the tings I have been working with but nothing seems to work.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET Email = alert_email  
WHERE alert_email = Email = '' 
And alert_email = NULL 
LIMIT 200
```

I run this command and it says zero rows effected and I still see empty alert_email values.

Comment: What is your database engine? MSSQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

To update alert_email to email (MSSQL):

```
update users
set alert_email = email
where alert_email is null or (alert_email = '' and email <> '')
```

Aside: zero rows affected means nothing has changed.

Comment: This is what I have as a final version running it now. UPDATE users SET alert_email = email WHERE alert_email is null LIMIT20;

Comment: UPDATE users SET alert_email = email LIMIT 2; this worked for me thank you for your help.